# Do I need an Office 365 to install Add-ins

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing Office Web Add-ins and I'd like to know if Office 365 subscription is required for users to install my add-ins from the store.

The documentation is not very precise about Office license type. I'm only sure that Exchange server is required. For example, if a user has a box license for Office, will he be able to see the Store button on the ribbon?

In other words, is the Office Web Add-ins installation dependent on Office license/subscription type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what Office license/subscription you used for installing Office. Mail Apps can work only in Exchange environments, i.e. for such types of accounts.

Comment: Thanks. I've got two different answers from MS support.